# MVC application - how to take care of caching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, web-config

I have a MVC + C# based application, which contains a lot of js files, images and css, basically static content. Its running on production as well. There was an issue reported by customer to which we provided an immediate solution by clearing cache on his machine. As per me, this should not be the ideal solution.
We have provided caching in our web.config file as given below:

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
</staticContent>
```

It is for one year, so how do i tackle this situation, as in if there is a new deployment to production, which has changes in static content, how do I make sure, the cache will be refreshed. Our prod deploy happens generally each 2 months.
And what are generally best practices for taking care of these cache things?
We also face this problem, when we do development, change static content, then our QA tests these, they dont find the changes, and we realize we have to clear cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Bundling` it for `js` and `Css`. Bundling takes care of caching.

It appends the url for a Bundle with some charactor.

If any changes comes in js or Css file it updates the appended url hence browser takes these file as new file and reloads it.

You can use Bundling with MVC3 and superior versions.

refer [this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: Looks good, have quite a few advantages. I am using ASP.NET4 with MVC3, but from the link it says it is for ASP.NET 4.5? Also, are there any other techniques, which are ONLY for caching issue as in my case. I agree, this bundling thing looks awesome, and I will be trying it out, but just curious, if there are other ways to tackle caching.

Comment: You can use bundling with mvc3 too follow this link  http://edspencer.me.uk/2013/02/20/using-mvc4-bundling-and-minification-in-an-mvc3-project/

Comment: Thanks Chandan, I will check if I can take this ahead.